# Azure Logic App: HTTP POST in For Each loop shows unauthorized error

Tags: azure-logic-apps

We have a problem with our logic app if we process multiple files in a For Each loop and try to do a HTTP POST to a Third-Party. Each file can have different urls/usernames/passwords for the HTTP POST step. This is why set username/password/url variables in our For Each.

Tests:

- If we test all these url's with logins with postman, it works.
- If we test different files with different username/password/url variables (but only one at a time per run) in our logic app, it works.
- If we test files with the same username/password/url for HTTP POST variables, it works.
- If we process multiple files at the same time with different usernames/passwords/url's for the HTTP POST step, it fails with some http posts in the for each showing UNAUTHORIZED, but if we check all the variables set for each file in the for each step it sets the correct username/password/url, these are correct.

Our conclusion:

If the http post gets dynamic variables (username/password/url) in a for each step some only some http post work. But for files with other login data, it fails. Looks like the HTTP connector cannot handle dynamic multiple http calls with different variables.

Our http post step:
[image]

Our if true condition inside a for each step (unautorized error while all login and url variables are correct):

[image]

Are we doing something wrong? Please help as we are trying to move this to production.

Comment: For Each loop in Logic Apps runs its iterations in parallel by default -- so if you've designed your workflow such that correct pair of username and password for their corresponding HTTP POST are determined at runtime in each iteration, based on original order of collection the loop began -- it'll probably produce the behavior you're observing. Assuming that was the case, have you tried running the loop with Sequential option on? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-control-flow-loops#sequential-foreach-loop

Comment: Thank you very much! if we set it sequential it works. But if the For Each step is set to sequential the step "Sharepoint - Move Files" fails inside the for each, saying: Failed to verify existence of source object. The move is executed and we see that the file has moved but the step fails. If we set the for each to not sequential it correctly moves the file but the HTTP step fails. I'm lost as to why it moves the file but fails. Do you have an idea?

Comment: Could you share screenshot of your existing LA workflow?

Comment: sorry, it is our own fault. The whole workflow works now, thanks to your suggestion! Can you post is as an answer on stackoverflow, i cannot approve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Each loop in Logic Apps runs its iterations in parallel by default -- so if you've designed your workflow such that correct pair of username and password for their corresponding HTTP POST are determined at runtime in each iteration, based on original order of collection the loop began -- it'll probably produce the behavior you're observing. Assuming that was the case, have you tried running the loop with Sequential option on?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-control-flow-loops#sequential-foreach-loop

Comment: thank you so much, but how can we actually debug or understand where exactly is the issue in Foe Each loop of Logic Apps?